# Where Can I Find Personal Advice for Options Trading?

Tags: options

I have spent the past several weeks researching options trading on the web. While I am confident with the key concepts, I feel that I could get caught out by technicalities when executing my first trade (e.g. lack of liquidity, large spreads, etc.).

I would like to make a serious commitment and purchase call options on oil. I think having an experienced person to talk to could help me avoid making beginner's mistakes when executing the order on a trading platform (e.g. Interactive Broker's TWS).

I would be grateful if someone could advise where I could find such a tutor/ mentor online.

Kind Regards, Will

Answer (score 0):

For trading American options, there is a site called Options Alpha. They have free memberships and have several hours of training videos.

I've gone through most of their videos and I found them very enlightening.

I understand that options rules are different in other countries. As I said, this is only for American trading.

Comment: You do realize that an American option is American called American because of its features, not because it is specific to the US ? Similarly European options are traded in the US.

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer to help you inadvertently buy $250,000 worth of call options if you'd like.  OK, just kidding.

Only a limited amount of chat is allowed here so a chat room would be more suitable.  However,  I just saw that you need a  need a 20 reputation to talk there. If that means two likes of your question, no problem.  That can be achieved easily.

I can try to help you if you're on Classic standalone TWS (not Mosaic) and not the web based version.  Have you determined what call you want to buy and have you entered the symbol into the platform?  We'll go at this until they chastise us :->)

Plan B is to use the IB Help index.  And while I've never looked at them, there are Interactive Broker tutorials on YouTube.  This one (or similar) might be useful [How to Use Interactive Brokers Platform to Place a Trade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQibl5TN1Rs).

Comment: Hi Bob, I'm absolutely chuffed that you've offered to help me - thank you! I take full responsibility for my choices but to have your informed thoughts will be much better than going it alone. If I may, I will carefully put together my plan of action and run it by you in the chat room. Hopefully, it could be beneficial for others to witness the questions raised when a beginner makes a trade. I'll see if I can start a chat. Best regards, Will

Answer (score 0):

There are some good books on options, such as Natenberg's [Options Volatility & Pricing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007VLQQU4) which goes through the mechanics.

Many brokerage firms have webinars, and the [Options Industry Council](https://optionseducation.org) usually have free events in a town near you (or webinar) where a seasoned options trader goes through the basics.

I would characterize options as 'playing with scalpels' in that they are very precision tools that only do certain things, are very expensive and if you are not very careful can hurt yourself very easily.   Before your broker allows you to trade, or can even discuss a specific strategy with you, he is required under the rules to have you sign the [OCC options disclosure document](https://www.theocc.com/about/publications/character-risks.jsp).  Anyone else who does not require that is presumably not registered so is not subject to regulatory oversight.

To add some perspective, Natenberg states that most option traders make their money by buying and selling theoretically mis-priced options. i.e. other participants (or their computers) are out in the market waiting for you to enter a mis-priced options order that they can trade against it and make a profit, and they may be using more sophisticated pricing models and strategies than your broker provides, and more powerful computers and better market data than you may have available.

You could also open an account with a "higher touch" but more expensive broker to get some hand holding by a registered person while you get started.  You would pay more for transaction fees, but should get feedback and have someone to discuss with before placing trades.

If you do decide to move forward with placing trades without a lot of preparation, I would suggest trying 'paper trading' first - where you use a brokerage account without real money, to see how you do, and when you start trading for real, do small trades where you can afford to make a loss.  You are more likely to make mistakes at the beginning.  Don't let the mistakes wipe you out.